# Tags page filter/search is out of sync when going "back" to it

Tags: bug, tags, back-button, tags-page

Browser: Chrome 37.0.2062.122
Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a site's tags page, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags.
2. Type something in the “Type to find tags:” box.
3. Click on one of the tags, going to `/questions/tagged/...`
4. Go back.

At this point, **what you typed in the filter box will still be present, but the list of tags will *not* be filtered.**

Besides just being a bug because things are inconsistent, this is specifically inconvenient if you're trying to learn about several tags that match your filter by seeing what questions each one is tagged with.

Comment: The back button does appear to be borked for a few weeks now. If I remember correctly it used to bring you to the updated info, but now it just seems to bring you to the previous info. Haven't tried the tagged page, just in general on like questions and answers.